# Auto Refresh textview

Tags: android

I want to create one app. which get score from Server in json and display it on my app. but auto refresh is not working.
when it get auto refresh it's showing two values old one and updated value too.

```
String s1=" ";
String s2=" ";
String s3=" ";
String s4=" ";
String s5=" ",s6=" ",s7=" ",s8=" ",s9=" ",s10=" ",s11=" ",s12=" ",s13=" ";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    resultview1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1_1);
    resultview2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1_2);
    resultview3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    resultview4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.comm1);
    resultview5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team2_1);
    resultview6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team2_2);
    resultview7=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.comm2);
    resultview8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team3_1);
    resultview9=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team3_2);
    resultview10=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.comm3);
    resultview11=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team4_1);
    resultview12=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.team4_2);
    resultview13=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.comm4);




    //new BackHelper().execute();
    mHandler();


}

private void mHandler() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 15000);
} 





public void  getdata1()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s1= s1 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t1")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t1_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t1_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t1_0");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}





public void  getdata2()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s2= s2 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t2")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t2_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t2_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t2_o");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata3()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s3= s3 
                    +json.getString("date");


        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}




public void  getdata4()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s4= s4 
                    +json.getString("comm");


        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata5()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team2.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s5= s5 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t1")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t1_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t1_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t1_0");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}


public void  getdata6()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team2.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s6= s6 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t2")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t2_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t2_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t2_o");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata7()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team2.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s7= s7+json.getString("comm");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata8()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team3.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s8= s8 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t1")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t1_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t1_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t1_0");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata9()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team3.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s9= s9 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t2")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t2_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t2_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t2_o");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}

public void  getdata10()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team3.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s10= s10 +json.getString("comm");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}


public void  getdata11()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team4.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s11= s11 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t1")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t1_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t1_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t1_0");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}

public void  getdata12()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team4.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s12= s12 +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("t2")+"\n"+"Run : "+json.getInt("t2_r")+"/"+json.getInt("t2_w")+"\n"+
                       "Over : "+json.getInt("t2_o");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}



public void  getdata13()
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.3gsngarbagroup.com/master/team4.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr= entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        //resultview.setText("could not connect to database");
    }
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s13= s13 +json.getString("comm");

        }

        //resultview.setText(s);

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());

    }
}
```

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

```
private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable () 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name) + " ChatList.updateTask()",
                "updateTask run!");

                    // run any code here...
        //getdata();
        new BackHelper().execute();
        Log.e("hell", "hello");
        // queue the task to run again in 15 seconds...
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 15000);
    }
};





 class BackHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        getdata1();
        getdata2();
        getdata3();
        getdata4();
        getdata5();
        getdata6();
        getdata7();
        getdata8();
        getdata9();
        getdata10();
        getdata11();
        getdata12();
        getdata13();



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //super.onPostExecute(result1);
        resultview1.setText(s1);
        resultview2.setText(s2);
        resultview3.setText(s3);
        resultview4.setText(s4);
        resultview5.setText(s5);
        resultview6.setText(s6);
        resultview7.setText(s7);
        resultview8.setText(s8);
        resultview9.setText(s9);
        resultview10.setText(s10);
        resultview11.setText(s11);
        resultview12.setText(s12);
        resultview13.setText(s13);



    }






}
```

}

Comment: this is because you are appending new information to the String variable every time.

Comment: Are you really querying the same server (okay, four different pages) 13 times in separate methods  to fill 13 variables? And what about using arrays?

Comment: Please - read the first comment and fix your bug, then read the second comment and fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

check my comment ur running in conning loop

```
private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable () 
{
  public void run() 
 {
    Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name) + " ChatList.updateTask()",
            "updateTask run!");

                // run any code here...
    //getdata();
    new BackHelper().execute();
    Log.e("hell", "hello");
    // queue the task to run again in 15 seconds...
 // here i think your in continues loop. check
    mHandler.postDelayed(updateTask, 15000);
}
 };
```